# Django 1.9 - url internationalization

Tags: python, django, internationalization, django-1.9

I am trying to setup a project in Django 1.9 and I have trouble to translate the home page.

I would like to redirect my users to /en or /fr when they hit the home page.

So I checked the documentation but it's not quite clear for me.

In my settings.py, I added this (from doc: [url internationalization](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/i18n/translation/#url-internationalization)):

```
MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES += [
    'django.middleware.locale.LocaleMiddleware',
]
```

I also have this:

```
LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en'
DEFAULT_LANGUAGE = 'en'
LANGUAGES = (
    ('en', 'English'),
    ('fr', 'Français'),
)
TIME_ZONE = 'America/Toronto'
USE_I18N = True
USE_L10N = True
USE_TZ = True
```

In my urls.py, I added:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from django.conf.urls import url
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _
from django.views.generic.base import TemplateView

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', TemplateView.as_view(template_name="index.html"), name='home'),
    url(_(r'^privacy-policy/$'), TemplateView.as_view(template_name="privacy-policy.html"), name='privacy-policy'),
]
```

When I run the server and go to localhost:8000, there is no redirect to /en or /fr

What I am doing wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not exactly sure about django 1.9, but in 1.8 you need to declare your i18n urlpatterns this way :

```
# your_project/your_project/urls.py
from django.conf.urls import include, url
from django.contrib import admin
from django.conf.urls.i18n import i18n_patterns

urlpatterns += i18n_patterns(
    url(r'^test$', 'your_package.views.test', name='test'),
)
```

We made an article on my company blog a few month ago if it can help you http://www.metod.io/en/blog/2015/05/05/django-i18n-part-1/

Comment: I know but in the doc, they said:

`Deprecated since version 1.8:`
`The prefix argument to i18n_patterns() has been deprecated and will not be supported in Django 1.10. Simply pass a list of django.conf.urls.url() instances instead.`

Comment: @Kornikopic In Django >1.8: `urlpatterns += i18n_patterns([url(r'^test$', 'your_package.views.test', name='test')])`

Comment: @JamesFenwick that's exactly what I trying to avoid since this feature will be removed in Django 1.10 - also I tried it and it does not work. Here the error I got: `AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'regex'`

Comment: Indeed you're right about the version 1.8 deprecation. However in the [dev documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/i18n/translation/#module-django.conf.urls.i18n), the depreciation warning seems to have disappeared, and they keep the mention of i18n_patterns, so I'm wondering which version is right. Regardless, have you tried calling your view in the url without using the generic TemplateView ?

Comment: In Django 1.10 the function will only take a pattern list `i18n_patterns(*pattern_list)` from `i18n_patterns(prefix, pattern_description, ...)`

Comment: @mrequillart Interesting. I hope it's just a mistake in their django 1.9 doc. I tried with the i18n_patterns() and it works.